# Properly using Facets for Algolia Search Results

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an indice with the following JSON key and can have either two values:

`ApprovalFL: true` OR `ApprovalFL: null`

I’d like my search result to display only the results that have `ApprovalFL: true` meaning that they have been approved to display on the site.

I tried looking into the Algolia Facet method ( https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/#search-for-facet-values ), but I’m honestly not too sure where to put it in my code, (dev initially set up Algolia…I’m still learning) here’s my relevant javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/vpnvt9vv/1

Here's a snippet of my code, the rest is found in the link above:

```
var searchSong = instantsearch
    ({
        appId: "---",
        apiKey: "---",
        indexName: "Song",
        searchFunction: function (helper) {
            var query = searchArtist.helper.state.query;

            helper.state.index = "Song";
            helper.state.hitsPerPage = 30;
            helper.setQuery(query);
            helper.search();
        },
        searchParameters:
        {
            hitsPerPage: 30
        }
    });
```

I’ve already added the key to “attributesforFaceting” in the Algolia Dashboard page.

If you'd like to see a live example, go https://unearthapp.io and type in the search bar the letter "a" you'll see two results from an artist called "Turbo" that have an ApprovalFL of null when I only want songs with ApprovalFL of true to display

Let me know if you need any more info, thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting `facetFilters` to `["ApprovalFL:true"]`? Try placing this in the `searchFunction` or `searchParameters`.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi i guess my question is, where do I place that exactly?

Comment: `options.helper.setQuery(e.currentTarget.value).addFacetRefinement('ApprovalFL', true).search()` may be this line in the `init` function? Try with string "true" as well.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi says that it expects ";" error https://snag.gy/3kRLNv.jpg

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I found this reference but I'm not sure where I'd put it in reference to my code: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `facetFilters` and set it to `["ApprovalFL:true"]`

[**FACET FILTERS**](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/)

From your code structure, you can add it either in the `searchFunction` **OR** in the `searchParameters` something like below. Ideally, you would want to add search filters once in your code otherwise the code could get unpredicatable due to the declaration at many places.

```
var searchSong = instantsearch ({
    appId: "---",
    apiKey: "---",
    indexName: "Song",
    searchFunction: function (helper) {
        .
        .
        .
        helper.state.facetFilters = ["ApprovalFL:true"];
        .
        .
        .       
    },
    searchParameters: {
        hitsPerPage: 30,
        facetFilters: ["ApprovalFL:true"]
    }
});
```